# Chrome --user-data-dir over shared network, possible?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, network-shares, symbolic-link

Is it possible to open Chrome with the user data directory on the shared network drive specified?

The background why I'm trying this is: I have two computers. I use one mainly and the second one is for automated tasks or cpu/gpu heavy tasks, so it doesn't affect the main one where I usually working upon like coding or web browsing. These days I run a Chrome instance that is for automated tasks and monitering tasks and also cpu consuming, I wanted to migrate it to the second computer. Now the problem is how to migrate the directory specified by --user-data-dir to the destination computer. I don't like to just copy the entire folder to the computer, it's a gigabytes of data, it takes time for the deploying. I'd rather want it to be mirrored synchronously. So I thought using symbolic link should solve the issue. So I tried as follows:

Let's say I usually open the Chrome instance like this:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="T:\_chromeShared" --silent-debugger-extension-api --enable-logging --v=0 --profile-directory="Default"
```

So, sharing the _chromeShared folder over the local network on the main computer, I then run the following on the second computer.

```
cmd.exe /c mklink /D "C:\_chromeShared_symlink" '\\192.168.1.123\_chromeShared'
cmd.exe /c mklink /J "C:\_chromeShared" "C:\_chromeShared_symlink"
```

Now the symlink has been created without a problem or an error. For example when I create a new file C:_chromeShared\newFile.txt on the second computer, it instantly gets mirrored to the main computer's T:_chromeShared\newFile.txt.

So now I tried to test if the Chrome instance can launch:

```
chrome.exe  --user-data-dir="C:\_chromeShared" --silent-debugger-extension-api --enable-logging --v=0 --profile-directory="Default"
```

But I got an error:

```
> chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:\_chromeShared" --silent-debugger-extension-api --enable-logging --v=0 --profile-directory="Default"
PS C:\Users\tmp> [12340:11732:0723/093855.503:ERROR:os_crypt_win.cc(102)] Failed to decrypt: Key not valid for use in specified state. (0x8009000B)
[12340:11732:0723/093856.321:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[12340:11732:0723/093856.916:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[12340:11732:0723/093857.149:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[12340:11732:0723/093857.609:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[12340:11732:0723/093857.744:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[12340:11732:0723/093858.034:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[12340:11732:0723/093858.154:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[12340:11732:0723/093858.188:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[12340:11732:0723/093858.211:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=2
[12340:11732:0723/093858.212:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(431)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
```

So, again, (how) is it possible to Chrome --user-data-dir over shared network? Thanks.